# Es posible crear un metodo que usa ruta GET para permitir que reciba dos parametros?

Tags: laravel-5

Necesito crear un metodo get que reciba dos parametros por parte de otro metodo que esta en la misma clase, he tratado pero no se como hacerlo, esto es lo que tengo..

```
 *
 * @param  string  $usuarios
 * @param  int  $usuariosOpciones
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function listado($usuarios, $usuariosOpciones)
{

    $usuarios=usuarios::orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(10);
    $usuariosOpciones =usuarios::pluck('usuario_ad', 'user_id')->unique();
    return view('usuario.listado',compact('usuarios','usuariosOpciones'));

}


  /**
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function selector(Request $request)

    {
        $tipo = $request->tipo;
        $usuarios=usuarios::where("user_id","=",$request->tipo)->paginate(10);
        $usuariosOpciones=usuarios::pluck('usuario_ad', 'user_id')->unique();
        $resultado=$this->listado($usuarios, $usuariosOpciones);
        return ($resultado);

    }
```

Adicional a esto.. como podria hacer para que el metodo selector llame al metodo listado y asi poderle enviar las variables que quiero.

Comment: Preferentemente pon el código en esta página y aclara tu pregunta porque está un tanto confusa y detalla un poco más tu código. ¿Un método get o una ruta tipo get?

Comment: ¿Por qué inicializas los parámetros `$usuarios` y `$usuariosOpciones` en la función `selector` si luego no haces nada con ellos? ¿Para qué le pasas esos parámetros a la función `listado` si no haces nada con ellos? No queda muy claro qué pretendes hacer ni la separación entre ambas funciones

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con un **`return`** directamente a la función listado, de esta manera:

```
 /**
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */



public function selector(Request $request)
    {
        $tipo = $request->tipo;
        $usuarios=usuarios::where("user_id","=",$request->tipo)->paginate(10);
        $usuariosOpciones=usuarios::pluck('usuario_ad', 'user_id')->unique();
        return $this->listado($usuarios, $usuariosOpciones);
    }
```